# Error while importing Certificate with Private key

Tags: certificate, private-key, x509certificate2

I want to create an `X509Certificate2` object in my C# by importing a Certificate which contains private key.

This certificate I have exported from my Database using the following LOC –

`BACKUP CERTiFiCATE TestCert
       TO FiLE = 'C:\Avdhut\TestCert1.cer'
WiTH PRiVATE KEY
       (
              FiLE = 'C:\Avdhut\TestCertWithPrivateKey.cer',
              ENCRYPTiON BY PASSWORD = 'wiND0w5'
       )`

I have the following C# code –

`X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Avdhut\TestCertWithPrivateKey.cer", "wiND0w5");`

It however throws an exception stating –
**CryptographicException was unhandled**
Cannot find the requested object

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your certificate file is malformed (formatted in PEM) and which is not supported by .NET. Look in this thread for additional information: [How do I use a private key in C#? "Cannot find the requested object."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754685/how-do-i-use-a-private-key-in-c-cannot-find-the-requested-object)